# How to conditionally combine two PySpark Dataframes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two Dataframes. Please tell me how I can join the two Dataframes to give all columns from both, while for the common columns, take the values from the first Dataframe unless the value is `null`, in which case replace it with the value from the second Dataframe.

Here's an example:

df1

```
id   col1    col2   col3
 1     15      20      8
 2      0    null      5
```

df2:

```
id   col1    col2    col4
 1     10      10      40
 2     10      30      50
```

Desired result:

```
id  col1 col2 col3 col4
 1    15   20    8   40
 2     0   30    5   50
```

Comment: In order to understand what you are trying to achieve, what operation (in words) are you performing in your example to get the result?

Comment: join dataframe with union column

Comment: From your example, it looks like what you want to achieve is to join the two dataframes on id to give you the additional column col4 and for col1,col2,col3 take the values from df1 unless the value is null, in which case replace it with the value from df2? If so, you really need to explain this better in your question. The question is currently not clear and has received down votes as a result.

Comment: Yes. You're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` on `id`, followed by `when`/`otherwise` pattern is what you are after. This code works for your example:

```
  from pyspark.sql.functions import when

  result = (df1.join(df2, on=['id']).
            withColumn('_col1', when(df1['col1'].isNotNull(), df1['col1']).otherwise(df2['col1'])).
            withColumn('_col2', when(df1['col2'].isNotNull(), df1['col2']).otherwise(df2['col2'])).
            select('id', '_col1', '_col2', 'col3', 'col4').
            toDF('id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'))
```

Comment: I didn't think you could use columns from different dataframes in Spark, have I missed something

Comment: The answer joins two dataframes on a common `id` column in order to use colums from either dataframe depending on the condition.

Comment: Does this code actually run for you? because spark doesn't support using columns from different dataframes i.e. in one column expression. I just ran this code on Spark 2.4 and it does not run

Comment: Thanks. Will look tomorrow.

Comment: Actually ignore me, I had a type in the df it works and that has just blown my mind. Looking at the logical plan it creates a project with all columns from both dataframes Project [id#431L, col1#432L, col2#433L, col3#434L, col1#440L, col2#441L, col3#442L] so referencing to df[col1] df2[col1] internally translates to col1#432L and the other #440L 

Comment: Nice. You have thought through it much more than I did at the time.

Comment: haha I did think it was rushed as  '_col1' as doesn't actually do anything. 
But you've stumbled upon a nice bit undocumented Spark functionality. 
Did you read/ learn about somewhere?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, but I don't think it is a case of using a column from a different dataframe (the withColumn expression is purely acting on the dataframe resulting from the join). Using the reference to the original dataframe allows you to disambiguate which column you are referring to in the current dataframe when it has multiple columns with the same name.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's what I mean by the physical plan. This gives you a way of referencing otherwise ambiguous columns, in the physical plan calling df1['col1'] refers to col1#432L and df2['col1'] col1#440L

Answer (score 0):

You can combine 2 dataframes based on id:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'id')
df
```

Comment: This duplicates columns and does not remove null values.

Comment: Can you please show the data where is it duplicating with null values . The question was regarding combining the dataframes

Comment: The question shows the desired output (last code block), which is not what your solution produces.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is :

```
import pandas as pd

id=[1,2]
col1= [15,0]
col2=[20,'']
col3=[8,5]

dict_1 = {'id':id,'col1': col1, 'col2': col2, 'col3':col3}
df1= pd.DataFrame(dict_1)


id=[1,2]
col1= [10,10]
col2=[10,30]
col3=[40,50]

dict_2 = {'id':id,'col1': col1, 'col2': col2, 'col3':col3}
df2= pd.DataFrame(dict_2)

df_merge = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df_merge
```

**Output**
[image]